# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/DynamicPropertyFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I have a Spring Boot project with the following gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.15'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test.paltform'
version = '0.0.1'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.9")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-jre'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'    
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I run the project into IntelliJ the project is starting properly. When I compile it into docker image using this docker file:

```
# Use a Java runtime as the base image
FROM openjdk:21-slim-buster

VOLUME /tmp

# Copy the built JAR file into the container
ADD build/libs/test-platform.jar test-platform.jar

# Expose the default port for the app
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the app when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "test-platform.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/home/config/test-platform-configuration.yml"]
```

And use this docker command:

```
// execute Java -jar ... and build docker image
sh 'chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew clean build --no-daemon'

//sh 'docker build -t spring-boot-microservice .'
sh 'docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} .'
```

When I run the code into a kubernetes pod I get error:

```
2024-02-20 15:12:43.525  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2024-02-20 15:12:43.823  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-20 15:12:44.423 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:423) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at com.platform.Application.main(Application.java:25) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[test-platform.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[test-platform.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[test-platform.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[test-platform.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/DynamicPropertyFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4936) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:914) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/DynamicPropertyFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/DynamicPropertyFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:156) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointServlet.instantiateClass(EndpointServlet.java:51) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointServlet.<init>(EndpointServlet.java:46) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixStreamEndpoint.get(HystrixStreamEndpoint.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixStreamEndpoint.get(HystrixStreamEndpoint.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.DiscoveredServletEndpoint.<init>(DiscoveredServletEndpoint.java:47) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ServletEndpointDiscoverer.createEndpoint(ServletEndpointDiscoverer.java:68) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ServletEndpointDiscoverer.createEndpoint(ServletEndpointDiscoverer.java:42) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getFilterEndpoint(EndpointDiscoverer.java:307) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.isFilterMatch(EndpointDiscoverer.java:285) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.isEndpointExposed(EndpointDiscoverer.java:254) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.convertToEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:181) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/DynamicPropertyFactory
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet.<clinit>(HystrixMetricsStreamServlet.java:56) ~[hystrix-metrics-event-stream-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:200) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:549) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[test-platform.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
        ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Do you know what might cause this issue? I cleared several times `.gradle` folder into Jenkins server to delete the cache but still the problem is present.